# cross platform application development

Tags: cross-platform, mobile-phones

I have created an application in c language and its **executable file works fine in windows machine.** Now i want that this application should work in other platforms like **linux,mac** and also on **mobile OSs (iphone,androide,blackberry,symbian,etc..).**

`I don't want to recode it whole again for all these platforms.`

I had found flex as alternative as it works on browser so it is platform independent but i am not finding the way of managing video encoding and such kind of things through actionscript 3. It says that some stuffs we can achieve through `Native Processes` but then it will not true cross platform.

**I want my application run on all available platforms with minimal effort to write code again.**

e.g. `Write code once for all.`

What Is the way to achieve this ? I had seen many applications running on different platforms does they have done re-coding for every platform ?

I had heard that there is a software that converts code in different languages. If anyone knows about it, it will also helpful to me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the only sensible answer here is to use some kind of a web application as HTML is relatively the most universal/cross platform-friendly presentation method.

What I would do is I would create a front end first (let's say using ASP .NET) which would look similar on all platforms you're interested in, then I would compile your c code to a dll and just hook up this dll to your front end exposing its selected functions. Alternatively you can use that dll to create a web service exposing desired functions of your code.

I've seen a few such 100% cross platform applications and to be honest none of them was something more than just decent. I believe the whole effort you're going to put in making your app **really** platform friendly you could invest better in creating a web service unifying the business logic for all of them and creating native UI for each environment so the app feels friendly for all kinds of users.

Comment: Thanks Piotr for your reply i really liked your answer. my query is now that my application is about video streaming and send it to other say video calling like stud does we can achieve it through webservice?

Comment: Hi Hemant, of course, you can stream using a web service (simple WCF example here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/UploadlargeFilesWCFHTTP.aspx) but I guess your problem now is an application capable of reading and presenting the streamed data. I don't think you can create just one app to work the same way on all platforms, there's just too much involved in playing streamed videos. But my advice would be to focus on just one platform and if the idea catches, slowly move it to the others as well. Remember, it's not about your time as a developer, but about the users and their time.